# User designed login

Tags: login, customization

I want to have a custom login of my own, i.e., it can be face recognition based, biometric based etc.. The entire code for those portions will be written and validated by me. I just want that the os avoids its default login scheme and first runs my code for login. If its failing for a certain number of times, then it will reissue its default process.

Though I have obtained links like this: http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/05/face-authentication-face-recognition.html, still it is not what I desire to do...

Is this possible in Ubuntu? Any reply would be of immense help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facial recognition is convenient, but anyone can hold a picture of your face in front of the web cam

Comment: Look up PAM. You'll need to use PAM to interface with the login process

Comment: It's done.. Thanks for your support and guidance in the right direction.. For all those who are interested to work in similar subject can get a nice idea from.. https://github.com/ivgiuliani/RDM630-RFID-Reader